# How to get the version of the latest change of trunk?

Tags: svn

I'm trying to get the SVN version of the latest change happened in `trunk`. There are many other changes in branches, but I need to get the version number of the latest change in `trunk`. Is it possible to do this with SVN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The svn info command will tell you

`svn info https://svn.server.com/repo/project/trunk`

will give you lots of info - particularly you want to look at `Revision` (the global repo revision) and `Last Changed Rev` the revision of the path in the info command - in this case the trunk.

Comment: `svn info` will return me the latest version of entire repository, not of `trunk`

Comment: @yegor256, you're half right.  As I noted above, svn info returns the Revions and the Last changed rev.  You can check it out by looking at the svn info  http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk and http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/svn_mutex  notice that the Revision is the same, but the last changed revision is different - it reflects the last change for that path.

Answer (score 0):

```
svn info <Repository-URL>.
```

You can get more info from [this](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html)

Comment: `svn info` returns the latest version of the entire repo, not of `trunk`

Comment: `svn info` gives the info about the the repo in the `url`. If the `url` points to the trunk, then you can get the required info of the trunk.

Comment: @Balanivash is correct - the info command not only give you the global repository revision but the Last changed revision of the URL provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can script this pretty easily

```
~ cd <trunk>
~ svn log -l 1 --xml -v
```

Answer (score 0):

to see last changes in context

```
svn  diff -rPREV:HEAD [file]
```

or just to see just changes

```
svn  diff -rPREV:HEAD [file]|grep "^[+|-]"
```